# Do I need Bind for my dedicated server?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, debian-wheezy

On the onset, would like to declare myself as a newbie, I have used managed servers before, this time around wanted to go for nginx, and my host did not have a control panel for nginx only, and offered me to choose the unmanaged way.I have Debian Wheezy, nginx box. Well, its a hell of a learning experience to do everything manually, but its good to learn a new stuff, completed most of the stuff, but I am stuck with the DNS part.

My question is

1) I have created the glue records for ns1.example.com and ns2.eample.com on my domain registrar and they point to the static Ip provided by my hosting company, now the question is do I have to setup Bind on my server to resolve the name servers?

2) If yes, then would that have to be a master-slave configuration as I have only one server.

Comment: You'd likely be better off having a third-party host your DNS, like Amazon's Route53 offering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have only one server and domain, it's not useful to host your own DNS. Either use a registrar that offers DNS services or use a third-party provider for this. DNS can be tricky to get right and getting it wrong usually results in strange, hard-to-diagnose problems down the road.

Comment: I think there's much to be said for learning experiences, and for controlling as much of your own infrastructure as possible - but SvW is completely right that it requires more than one server.

Comment: I have already accepted the answer, but just an afterthought, whether I will be able to use the custom name servers created with my domain registrar, if not then, how was this possible when I had a vps, I don't think I had bind or other DNS server with my vps, I created nameservers on my domain registrar and pointed them to the ip provided.